# Install correct video driver based on PNP ID

Tags: wmi

I am very new at scripting and I need some help. I have an unattended windows XP install that I created. We use two different Nvidia cards, about 50 of each, they use different drivers. I would like to be able to install the correct driver, based on the PNP Device ID. The script below outputs the PNP Device ID, next I want to capture the PNP Device ID and install the correct driver. I just need to be able to read the PNP Device ID, then run a silent install for the correct driver and software. I need to have the full Nvidia software installed, not just the driver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Paul

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")

For Each objItem in colItems
 For Each strCapability in objItem.AcceleratorCapabilities
    Wscript.Echo "Accelerator Capability: " & strCapability
Next
      Wscript.Echo "PNP Device ID: " & objItem.PNPDeviceID
Next

Const EVENT_SUCCESS = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Windows PowerShell for this, instead of VBscript. If you're new to scripting, then I'd suggest that learning PowerShell would be much more advantageous than learning VBscript. You'll be able to do a lot more, with a lot less code.

Let's move on to some code:

```
# If a video controller matches the string on the right of the -match operator ...
if ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController) -match 'VEN_10DE&DEV_0DFC') {
    # ... then run this program
    Start-Process -FilePath setup.exe -ArgumentList '/silent /log:"nvidia.log"';
}
```